# Is there an application that wraps a website in itself?

Tags: software-recommendation, application-development, browser

I am looking for an application that is configurable to open a website on a certain address, having the website's logo as logo in the Launcher, without the browser bar, so I can run the website as if it were an application.
This is preferable for me to opening the website in the browser itself (you'll have to enter the address, or ctrl-tab to the right tab, alt-tab to the right window).
Thanks in advance for any advice. Advice how to customize browsers to do just what I want in this sense is also appreciated.

Comment: embedded gtk webkit browser for the desktop.  i hear sencha is working on something for this.  it already exists for webapps for android and iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Epiphany (gnome browser) has that feature.

You have to save that web site as a web app first.

Comment: I'm going to try this out!

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I meant. Great!

Answer (score 1):

### HTTrack

HTTrack is a web-based program that allows users to copy any website to your local hard drive for offline browsing. Nothing complicated with this website copier due to its plain web interface, you insert some few details about the website to download and let HTTrack do the rest, which will copy every page on the website, images, backgrounds, and every file hosted on that server with support of resuming interrupted downloads or updating existing mirrored websites.

[image]

The latest version of HTTrack is 3.46-1 which hasn't yet landed in the official Ubuntu repository (only for Quantal currently), but you can install it from our custom PPA as described below for Ubuntu 12.04/11.10/11.04. This version brings better unicode filenames handling and many bug fixes.

**How to Install**
Run this in the terminal (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd>)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:upubuntu-com/web
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install webhttrack httrack
```

To browse copied websites, you can check them in the "websites" directory located on your home.

For more information on httrack, [visit their home page](http://www.httrack.com/html/overview.html).

[Source](http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/07/httrack-346-1-website-copier-released.html)

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted, good suggestion though for people that want to copy a website. I'd just want a browser wrapper (so online, not offline) for one certain site.